# Unable to set PATH in WebStorm for Android SDK in Apache Cordova in MAC OS

Tags: android, cordova, installation, webstorm, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to Apache Cordova and making Hybrid Applications. 
I have tried all the options but I am still not able to give my Android SDK Path in WebStorm (the IDE that I am using). I am using Mac Machine running on OS Mojave.

```
sudo export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/nabiharaza/Library/Android/sdk"
sudo export PATH="$HOME/Android/tools:$/Users/nabiharaza/Library/Android/sdk"
sudo export PATH="$HOME/Android/platform-tools:$/Users/nabiharaza/Library/Android/sdk"
```

I have already run these commands on the terminal.
The path where my SDK is `"/Users/nabiharaza/Library/Android/sdk"`

Can someone help me with fixing this issue.

[image: See the picture here of WebStorm]

Comment: `export` commands you run in terminal only affect current terminal session, and only those programs that are started from this terminal instance will see your variables.

Answer (score 0):

when you run `sudo export`, you won't change anything to the shell of the *current* user. you have to edit `~/.bashrc` (or however the *current* user's profile would be called on OSX; just see `ls -la $HOME`) and add this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/nabiharaza/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
```